# Iterator in ArrayDeque

Tags: java, arraydeque

How to change this to ArrayDeque. I tried to do it but it gives me a Iterator error. Thanks for help.

```
void insert(List<String> l) {
    ListIterator<String> iter = l.listIterator();
    int i = 0;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        iter.next();
        if (i % 2 != 0) 
           iter.add("b");
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: add do ArrayDeque for a loop to the odd positions string "b"

Answer (score 2):

This Following code will help you iterate through the ArrayDeque Elements:

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

            ArrayDeque<String> queue = new ArrayDeque<String>();
            queue.add("A");
            queue.add("B");
            queue.add("C");
            queue.add("D");
            Iterator itr = queue.iterator();
       System.out.println("The Deque elements Iterate trough iterator : ");
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(itr.next());

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: must be in the loop

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `ListIterator` and the `listIterator` method which only work for implementations of the `List` interface, use the more general purpose `iterator` method which returns an `Iterator<E>` which exists for all implementations of the `Collection` interface, including `ArrayDeque`.

```
void insert(ArrayDeque<String> deque) {
    Iterator<String> iter = deque.iterator();
    int i = 0;
    while (iter.hasNext() {
        iter.next();
        if (i % 2 != 0) deque.add("b");
        i++
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: The method add(string) is udenfined for the type iterator<String>

Answer (score -1):

This is just an updated version of @Shadowfacts

```
void insert(ArrayDeque<String> deque) {
Iterator<String> iter = deque.iterator();
int i = 0;
while (iter.hasNext() {
    iter.next();
    if (i % 2 != 0) deque.add("b");
    i++
   }
}
```